# How to set UIButton an action implement by method with parameters?

Tags: ios, uibutton, selector

Is it possible to pass parameters to selector on this method?

```
addTarget:<(nullable id)> action:<(nonnull SEL)> forControlEvents:<(UIControlEvents)>
```

I created a custom button:

```
@interface ButtonToShare1 : UIButton
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *jsonArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *typeOfIcon;
@end
```

Also I set this class to the buttons in Storyboard.

[image: Storyboard connections]
[image: Storyboard connections 2]
So in following code

```
for (int i=0; i<json.count; ++i) {
            [_buttonsToShare[i] setImageForState:UIControlStateNormal withURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[json[i] valueForKey:@"size66"]]];
            ButtonToShare1 *buttonToShare = _buttonsToShare[i];
            buttonToShare.typeOfIcon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json[i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
            [_buttonsToShare[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(sendIcon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         }
```

I have an exception `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setTypeOfIcon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5661787b0'`
 at line

```
             buttonToShare.typeOfIcon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json[i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
```

P.S: The same happens even if i do the following:

```
 for (ButtonToShare1 *myButton in self.buttonsToShare) {
                [myButton setImageForState:UIControlStateNormal withURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[json[i] valueForKey:@"size66"]]];

                myButton.typeOfIcon =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json[i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
                [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendIcon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                i++;

            }
```

Comment: Read the docs for this. The action can have 0, 1, or 2 parameters. If 1, it is the button. If 2, it's the button and the event.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @ErmalKaleci I have 5 buttons and 5 arrays from json according to them. In json I have information about type of each button. E.g if button's type == "location" I need to pass the number of button (cycle's parameter in my case) to the method to display the map (other buttons must not show the map by tap).

Comment: One way: You can create custom button with weak reference to each array and access each array from method sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say this is our button

```
 @interface CustomButton : UIButton
 @property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *yourArray; // weak is fine
 @end
```

Implementation file

```
@implementation CustomButton
@end
```

you are creating buttons form storyboard and using IBAction or programmatically:

```
CustomButton *button = [[CustomButton alloc] init];
button.yourArray = //array here;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

tapped method

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(CustomButton *)button {
    // button.yourArray
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea. Why not just set the button's tag. Then the tag can be used to access the proper data.

Comment: View tag is primitive way and view tag is for this kind of thing. Doing like this you can access array directly and you are safe even you change number of buttons or view tags.

Comment: @ErmalKaleci Thanks for answer! But if i create custom button like this this (see the post), application throws exception at runtime with error `-[UIButton setTypeOfIcon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: @ArtStyle Did you fixed it?

Comment: You have to subclass the custom you are using. I guess your are using a custom Button?

Comment: Have enter CustomButton at storyboard class?

Comment: Select your button and enter ButtonToShare1 at custom class

Comment: Why are you doing this 'buttons[i] = buttonToShare;' ?

Comment: @ErmalKaleci Yes, i entered.  It is for get the array of buttons with type, because I can't write `buttons[i].typeOfIcon = type`

Comment: With that line you are just replacing the same object

Comment: Also you can create the buttons array from storyboard

Comment: create an collection of IBOutlets`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(ButtonToShare1) NSArray *buttons;`

Comment: `for (NSInteger i = 0; i < buttons.count; i++) { }`

Comment: @ErmalKaleci Did It. Have the same exception

Comment: @ArtStyle you are doing something wrong. Add some screenshots

Comment: @ArtStyle ensure that you are doing something like this to each buttons http://zappdesigntemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Setup-custom-class-identity-inspector-xcode-ios.png

Comment: @ArtStyle select the button and enter custom class

Comment: @ErmalKaleci Sure! Updated the post :)

Comment: @ArtStyle If you get an exception like "Unkown custom class" you have to define your custom button at .m file

Comment: @ArtStyle `@implementation ButtonToShare1
@end`

Comment: @ArtStyle also you don't need that `[_buttonsToShare[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(sendIcon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`. You can create target action from storyboard `- (IBAction)sendIcon:(ButtonToShare1 *)sender {}`

Comment: @ArtStyle just create button implementation on .m file and everything will be fine. Just empty implementation

Comment: @ArtStyle did you fixed it?

Comment: @ErmalKaleci Yes, You are exactly right! Implementation helped me :) Thank You a lot!